# Вывод содержимого файла в обратном порядке bash

Tags: linux, bash

подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести данные с файла в обратном порядке (bash).
Имеется код, но он выводит

```
11 12 13 14 15
 6 7 8 9 10
 1 2 3 4 5
```

Вместо

```
15 14 13 12 11
10 9 8 7 6 
5 4 3 2 1
```

```
reverse() {

  IFS=$'\n'
 for entry in $(tac "$1")
 do
 for value in $entry
 do
 echo " $value"
 done
done
}
```

Comment: *Awk* подойдёт, или нужен чистый *Bash?*

Comment: `perl -e 'print map{reverse /(\S+|\s+)/g} reverse <STDIN>' < numbers.txt`

Comment: `rev --help Использование: rev [параметры] [файл ...] Вывод строк файла задом наперёд.` не?